# No route matches error in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an issue regarding the route of a view. I have created a user Model and view using devise and also created a controller manually. All works fine, but after logged in, when I provide sign_in url an error occur instead of redirecting to home page
Error message is

```
No route matches {:action=>"timeline", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

     # else
     timeline_path(resource)
   end
```

I have created a path sign-in manually. Its not showing any error. But auto generated path (users/sign_in) by devise is giving the error .Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the complete method where you are providing the path.

Comment: Post the structure of your route.rb

Comment: the resource appears to be null. I recommend install the gem better_error to show debug in fast way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This might help you**

The `resource` object is nil. Since you are trying to go to current user timeline then you can use `timeline_path(current_user)`